# Python, Selenium : not able to find the fourth nested iFrames

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium in Python to automate some tasks on a webpage. The webpage has some nested iFrames, and I need to go deep into the fourth nested iFrame to click on a button. the first three nested iFrame can be fast switch to, but when it come to the fourth iFrame, I always get timeout error, even I've set the wait time up to 120s . Below is the Python code and HTML. iframe name="portalDisplay">is the third nested iframe and iframe name="ECMCOs" is the one I want to switch to and click a button inside it. Thanks!

```
browser.switch_to_default_content()
WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,'//iframe[@id="content"]'))) 
WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,'//div[@id="unique1"]/iframe[1]')))
WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,'//div[@id="divPageBody"]/iframe[1]')))
WebDriverWait(browser, 120).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,'.//iframe[@name="ECMCOs"]')))
```

```html
<iframe name="portalDisplay" src="emxPortalDisplay.jsp?portal=ECMEnterpriseChangeMgtPortal&amp;header=EnterpriseChangeMgt.Label.ECMChangeCOsCAsLeagcySummaryPageHeading&amp;emxSuiteDirectory=enterprisechangemgt&amp;treeLabel=91852699+001&amp;suiteKey=EnterpriseChangeMgt&amp;StringResourceFileId=emxEnterpriseChangeMgtStringResource&amp;SuiteDirectory=enterprisechangemgt&amp;objectId=20336.41905.42762.46685" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" border="0" cd_frame_id_="ca6315bf2f2783f6030dd845f480d61d">
#document
<html>
<head>..<head>
<body>
<!-- //XSSOK -->
<script language="javascript" src="/enovia/common/scripts/emxUICore.js"></script>
<!-- //XSSOK -->
<script language="javascript" src="/enovia/common/scripts/emxUIModal.js"></script>
<script language="Javascript"> 
</script>
<script language="JavaScript">   var DisplayErrorMsg = "";
 </script>

<div class="pv-container" id="divPowerView" data-portalname="ECMEnterpriseChangeMgtPortal" style="overflow-y: hidden;">
  <div class="pv-row" id="divPvRow-1" minsize="240" style="height: 709px;">
    <div class="pv-channel complex" id="divPvChannel-1-1" style="width: 100%; 
     float: right; height: 100%;">
       <div class="pv-channel-tabs" id="pvChannelTabs">
         <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"> 
          ....
          </div>
        <div class="pv-channel-content" style="">
           <div class="tab-header" style="display: none;"></div>
           <iframe name="ECMCOs" src="../common/emxIndentedTable.jsp? 
 sortColumnName=Name&amp;PrinterFriendly=true&amp;SuiteDirectory=enterprisechangemgt&amp;treeLabel=91852699+001&amp;parentOID=20336.41905.42762.46685&amp;emxSuiteDirectory=enterprisechangemgt&amp;HelpMarker=emxhelpchangeordersection&amp;program=enoECMChangeUtil%3AgetConnectedChanges&amp;functionality=isChangeOrderTab&amp;portalMode=true&amp;StringResourceFileId=emxEnterpriseChangeMgtStringResource&amp;toolbar=ECMChangeOrderManagementToolbar&amp;sortDirection=ascending&amp;selection=multiple&amp;portalCmdName=ECMCOs&amp;jsTreeID=null&amp;suiteKey=EnterpriseChangeMgt&amp;header=EnterpriseChangeMgt.Label.ECMChangeCOsCAsLeagcySummaryPageHeading&amp;portal=ECMEnterpriseChangeMgtPortal&amp;table=ECMChangeSummary&amp;objectId=20336.41905.42762.46685" frameborder="0" width="100%"></iframe></div>
<div class="pv-channel-content" style="display: none;">
<div class="tab-header" style="display: none;"></div><iframe name="ECMCRs" src="" frameborder="0" width="100%"></iframe></div><div class="pv-channel-content" style="display: none;"><div class="tab-header" style="display: none;"></div><iframe name="ECMChangeLegacy" src="" frameborder="0" width="100%"></iframe></div></div></div></div></body></html>
```

TML snippet`enter code here`:

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting the `display: none` property to `display : block` using javascript executor?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am not sure how to setting property using javascript executor in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were pretty close. Change the *Locator Strategy* from:

```
(By.XPATH,'.//iframe[@name="ECMCOs"]')
       ^ remove the dot
```

To:

```
(By.XPATH,"//iframe[@name='ECMCOs'][contains(@src,'/common/emxIndentedTable.jsp')]")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I changed according your advice, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I finally manage to fit it by using the following code:

```
browser.switch_to_default_content()
iframe1 = WebDriverWait(browser, 
120).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//iframe[@id="content"]')))
browser.switch_to.frame(iframe1.get_attribute('id'))
iframe2 = WebDriverWait(browser,120).until 
(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@id="unique1"]/iframe[1]')))
browser.switch_to.frame(iframe2.get_attribute('name'))
iframe3 = WebDriverWait(browser,120).until 
(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@id="divPageBody"]/iframe[1]')))
browser.switch_to.frame(iframe3.get_attribute('name'))
time.sleep(20)
iframe4 = WebDriverWait(browser, 120).until 
(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//iframe[@name="ECMCOs"]')))
browser.switch_to.frame(iframe4.get_attribute('name'))
```

1. use the frame name to switch (according to the advice [here](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/1969))
2. the tricky is use time.sleep() instead of browser.implicitly_wait(). I've tried browser.implicitly_wait() previously, but even I've set browser.implicitly_wait(70), still didn't work, and I've tried to print out the first iframe from the current note(.//iframe[0] ) I got iframe @id="content", it feel like I did't switch the frame. My guess is using implicit wait, WebDriver kind of go out of the iframe when it poll the DOM  trying to locate an element. While using sleep, WebDriver will stay in the iframe